# How to initialize objects inside foreach to push elements

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to build this JSON :

```
{
    "id": 20,
    "professions":
    [
        {
            "id_profession": 3853
        },
        {
            "id_profession": 3854
        }
    ]   
}
```

And my function is the next :

```
submitRegistration(value: Object): void {

        let nameGroup = value['name'];
        let type = value['type'];
        let sectorTemp: Sector = value['sectors'];

        let listProfessions: ProfessionGroup[];       
        let addProfessions: AddProfesions;

        (value['professions']).forEach(i=>{
            console.log(i.id);
            let oneProffesion:ProfessionGroup;
            oneProffesion.id_profession=i.id;
            listProfessions.push(oneProffesion);
        })

        console.log(listProfessions.length);       
    }
```

`value['professions']` return an object list and I need to get the id only .

The problem is that it allways return :

Cannot set property `'id_profession'` of `undefined`

In the loop foreach and I don't know why, I've tried to initialize it with null but doesn't function.

My interfaces are :

```
export interface Profession {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

export interface ProfessionGroup {
    id_profession: number;
}

export interface AddProfesions{
    id:number;
    professions:ProfessionGroup[];
}
```

Comment: You declare that `oneProffesion` variable but it is never initialized to a new value.

Comment: the `let oneProffesion:ProfessionGroup;` statement does not "initialize" an object, it just declares it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since defining a variable does not create object for it.

You have two ways to do so:

- **Assign Object to `ProfessionGroup` type**

  `let oneProffesion:ProfessionGroup;
  oneProffesion ={
           id_profession=i.id
      };`
- **Create class which implements `ProfessionGroup` type**

  `class ProfessionGroupClass implements ProfessionGroup{
    id_profession: number;
  }`

  now create new object of class

  `let oneProffesion:ProfessionGroup;
   oneProffesion=new ProfessionGroupClass();
   oneProffesion.id_profession=i.id;`

refer to the official [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) for same.

Answer (score 0):

This comes from the fact that declaring a variable in TypeScript does not really create it.

For example:

```
let variable: string;
```

In this example, `variable` contains `undefined` as this line is just there to specify the type of `variable`, but this line won't be included in the resulting JavaScript. However,

```
let variable: string = null;
```

Creates the variable with the `null` value in it. In your case, you must declare your `oneProffesion` variable as an empty object, then assign its properties or combine the declaration and the initialization:

```
let oneProffesion: ProfessionGroup = {
   id_profession: i.id
};
```

The same applies with your array. You should declare it like this:

```
let listProfessions: ProfessionGroup[] = [];
```

Otherwise, `listProfessions` is `undefined` an calling `push` on `undefined` result in an error.